# about the underlying meaning of 実際してない in this context

Tags: meaning, phrases

> woman 1 :就活している中で、私は将来、結婚したいなっていう気持ちもあるんですが。
> そこのところはどうですか?出世で遠のいてしまうイメージがあるので。
>
> woman 2 :一般的にどうかは置いといて、私の場合は遠のいているかもですね(笑) 実際してないですし。
> これまでも打診を受けるたびに悩みました。初めてマネージャーになる時に、当時付き合っていた方がいて。結婚も考えた時に完全に私のほうが収入も上がるし、役職も上がるしって思ったんですけど(笑)
>
> でも、その役職を引き受けるって決めて。 自分が稼ぐんだって決めて、実際になったら別れちゃったんです。

so , the first woman asks the second woman about her opinion of thinking about marriage and if it is going to affect her work in real life so i want know what does "実際してないですし" refer to here is it the fact the she is not married or is it that marriage does not affect your success in life

Answer (score 1):

> is it the fact the she is not married or is it that marriage does not affect your success in life

It's the former.

You could read the part like:

> 私の場合は（**結婚が**）[遠]{とお}のいているかもですね(笑) 実際（**結婚を**）してないですし。

In my case, (marriage) might have become distant (lol) In fact I am not (married).

Comment: i do not understand why would she use "一般的に" in this context and what does "打診を受ける" mean here

Comment: @lightofgold, 一般的に(in general) is in contrast to 私の場合は(in my case). It's like, 「一般的に(世間の他の人たちは)どうかは別にして、私個人は～」 "Setting aside how other people are in general, for me personally ~~" or "I can't speak for others, but for me personally..."  Does this make sense?

Comment: @lightofgold 打診を受ける here is talking about 昇進/promotion. 打診(する) means "to feel/sound (someone's view) out about (something, eg promotion)".

Comment: so basically she is saying that every time they tapped on the subject - her promotion - she would feel troubled ? 。is it because ":結婚も考えた時に完全に私のほうが収入も上がるし、役職も上がるしって思ったんですけど(笑)"  meaning she would earn more than her partner through the promotion or that she actively wanted to earn more and have a better occupation?

Comment: @lightofgold, 打診を受けるたびに悩みました　→ Every time their company suggested a promotion to her, she had a hard time deciding whether to accept or not.  完全に私のほうが収入も上がるし、役職も上がるしって思ったんですけど → She knew that she would earn more than her boyfriend and be in an upper position, でも、その役職を引き受けるって決めて → but she decided to accept the offer, 実際になったら → and when she actually got a promotion, 別れちゃったんです → she broke up with her boyfriend.